# find value from one column in one sheet to multiple column in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find out if value from one column of one sheet is present in anywhere (Any column/row) in another worksheet in excel. I am trying to use iferror(vlook function but it's only searching for a value in one column in another sheet. But i just want to see if value from one column from worksheet A is resent in worksheet B or not. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this formula you have:

1) Value to look up in cell A1

2) Sheet with the range you want to look in: Sheet2

3) Range to look in: Sheet2!A1:D2

Explanation:

This formula returns the row where a value is located in a Range

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!A1:D2=A1)*ROW(Sheet2!A1:D2))-ROW(Sheet2!A1:D2)+1
```

Then we test if it is result is 0 (because it doesn't exist in the Range) we can display found or not found

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!A1:D2=A1)*ROW(Sheet2!A1:D2))-ROW(Sheet2!A1:D2)+1>0;"found";"not found")
```

Adjust it to fit your needs

Comment: Can you please explain what is "-ROW(Sheet2!A1:D2)+1" doing to the formula?